# Unity 19.3.7f1 MRTK 2.4.0 can't connect HoloLens2 with Wi-Fi nor USB: NullReferenceException: DownloadHandler has already been destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I can connect HoloLens2 with Wi-Fi using Chrome by ip address:192.168.0.102, and the Windows Device Portal shows correctly. (I also installed the certificate to make a trust connection) 
[image]

But when I tried to connect it in Unity, it didn't work:
[image]

I have downloaded win10 SDK:
[image]

How can I fixed it?
I can give all of the log info if you need.
Waiting for your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Recommend you post here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude Thanks for advice, I've updated here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7734